# How to enable nautilus advanced permissions in configuration editor?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, configuration

I cant access show_advanced_permissions key on conf. editor. When open conf. editor on ubuntu 11.10 apps->nautilus->preferences only contains 5 key and show_advanced_permissions and a lot of key is missing, how to solve this problem (if this thing is a problem) sory my english.

Answer (score 3):

In 11.10 and newer Nautilus' advanced configuration can be found via `dconf-editor`, which you can get by installing [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools), then navigate to Org->gnome->Nautilus and browse around the keys.

[image]